# Powershell - if a process is not running, start it

Tags: powershell

Noob help please. I'm trying to write a script that will check if a process is running, and if not, start it. If the process is running, it should do nothing. I've come up with the following so far but it is starting a new instance of the process regardless of whether it was running already. Any help is appreciated.

```
$Prog = "C:\utilities\prog.exe"
$Running = Get-Process prog -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$Start = ([wmiclass]"win32_process").Create($Prog)
if($Running -eq $null)
{$Start}
else
{}
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

First of all, here's is what is wrong in your code.
In your code, the process is created before you evaluate whether your program is already running

```
$Prog = "C:\utilities\prog.exe"
$Running = Get-Process prog -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$Start = ([wmiclass]"win32_process").Create($Prog) # the process is created on this line
if($Running -eq $null) # evaluating if the program is running
{$Start}
```

It is possible to create a block of code that should be evaluated further in your code by wrapping it in {} (a scriptblock):

```
$Prog = "C:\utilities\prog.exe"
$Running = Get-Process prog -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$Start = {([wmiclass]"win32_process").Create($Prog)} 
if($Running -eq $null) # evaluating if the program is running
{& $Start} # the process is created on this line
```

However, if you're looking for a short one-liner to solve your problem:

```
if (! (ps | ? {$_.path -eq $prog})) {& $prog}
```

Comment: I don't get how your solution will solve the problem. The line `$Start = ...` will still start the process every time. I test ran the code and multiples of the same process were started. (make sure to test with a program that allows several instanses of itself)

Comment: Hi @LosManos, is it possible you forgot the {} (scriptblock)?

Comment: @jonZ Yes, that was the reason.

Answer (score 10):

In the [Get-Process cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176855.aspx), the process name argument must be **the name of the executable without the file extension**. Try substituting `$Prog = "C:\utilities\prog.exe"` with `$Prog = "prog"`.

In my opinion, your script would be more readable if you filtered the process out [using the Where-Object cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177028.aspx) instead. Here's an example:

```
$programName = "prog"
$isRunning = (Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $programName }).Count -gt 0

if ($isRunning)
 # ...
else
 # ...
```

That way you can get rid of the `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` argument, which can be confusing to someone who is not aware of the fact that [Get-Process](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176855.aspx) *throws an error* if it can't find a process with the specified name.

Comment: +1 because my mistake that led me here was that I was including the extension.

Answer (score 6):

```
$path = "C:\utilities\prog.exe"        
$list = get-process | where-object {$_.Path -eq $path }     
if ($list -eq $null) { start-process -filepath $path }
```

Or

```
$path = "C:\utilities\prog.exe"
get-process | where-object {$_.Path -eq $path } | measure-object | where-object { $_.Count -eq 0} | foreach-object {start-process -filepath $path }
```

This will save you the if statement and one variable declaration. It can be a one line command as well:

1. Get processes
2. Pick the ones with the path you are interested in
3. Use measure object to get the stats about the list you have
4. Continue the piping only if the count value of stats is 0
5. Start process

Don't let the foreach at the end put you off. The measure object will return only one item the where will return one or zero. The foreach is only used to execute if the result is zero. It won't start more then one processes. :)

Comment: No need to use measure/count. A value of 0 is treated as $false, non-zero is $true. Look at the end of jon-z's answer for the practical implementation.

Comment: You are right. Thank for the tip; I learned something new. jon-z's final example seems to be the nicest.

Answer (score 6):

Keep in mind that PowerShell handles objects and not just text. While in normal batch files you could set a variable to a string and then just use it as a command:

```
set Foo=dir /b
%Foo%
```

... this doesn't work in PowerShell. Thus your assignment of `$Start` already creates the new process since the command after the `=` is run and its result assigned to `$Start`.

Furthermore you're complicating things needlessly. I'd suggest the following instead:

```
$Running = Get-Process prog -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if (!$Running) { Start-Process C:\utilities\prog.exe }
```

Since `Get-Process` returns an object (which evaluates to `$true`) or `$null` (which evaluates to `$false`) you can simplify the check like shown above. This is called type coercion, since the `if` statement expects a boolean value and the rules on what will be treated as `$true` and `$false` are very consistent in such cases as above. And it reads nicer.

I also used the `Start-Process` cmdlet instead of WMI to create the new process. You could even use the following:

```
if (!$Running) { C:\utilities\prog.exe }
```

if the application is not a console application (and thus would block the PowerShell script until it exits). PowerShell is still a shell, so starting programs is something that works natively very well :-)

You could even inline the `$running` variable, but I guess a comment would be in order to clarify what you do, then.

Comment: You mentioned the true/false rules... A nice little post to help understand them by Jeffrey can be found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/12/24/boolean-values-and-operators.aspx).

Comment: I think the most confusing part about that is the rule with one-element arrays, but they make sense if you consider things like `@(...)` and thus behave as naïvely expected :-)