# PowerShell process check is starting too many processes

Tags: powershell, scripting

I'm using PowerShell to perform an hourly check to see if the "ASA" process is running. If not, then restart it. Using the code snippet found from jon Z's answer in the link below, its been working great. Maybe a little too good? [Powershell - if a process is not running, start it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8834278/powershell-if-a-process-is-not-running-start-it)

I have a scheduled task that runs this script every hour for 24 hours. The problem I'm noticing is that I have a bunch of ASA processes open, when I only need & want 1.

[image]

Here's my script. I also have the script double check itself to send me an email if it found that the process was not running, and to email me the results.

```
# Set some variables
$computer = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$prog = "C:\Program Files\Avaya\Site Administration\bin\ASA.exe"
$procName = "ASA"
$running = Get-Process $procName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$start = ([wmiclass]"win32_process").Create($prog) # the process is created on this line

# Begin process check
if($running -eq $null) { # evaluating if the program is running
    $start # Start the program
    sleep 5
    # Re-check the process to see if it is running
    $nowRunning = Get-Process $procName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    # Email us the results as to whether it started or was not able to restart. 
    if ($nowRunning -eq $null) {
        blat.exe - -priority 1 -to john@doe.com -server my.smtp.com -f john@doe.com -subject "ASA cannot be restarted on $computer!" -body "The latest powershell check showed that ASA was not running on $computer! ||PowerShell was not able to restart ASA. Please investigate."
        } else { 
        blat.exe - -priority 1 -to john@doe.com -server my.smtp.com -f john@doe.com -subject "ASA was restarted on $computer!" -body "The latest powershell check showed that ASA was not running on $computer! ||PowerShell was able to automatically restart ASA."
    }
}
```

My first assumption was that the process name was wrong and it should be the program name as defined in the Task manager. However according to this output, just using ASA, it is correct.

[image]

So I'm stuck as to why it's starting multiple instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time your script is executed it creates the process in this line:

```
$start = ([wmiclass]"win32_process").Create($prog) # the process is created on this line
```

the process it's always created , there's no check to create it if there isn't yet.

You have to change it like this

```
$start = '([wmiclass]"win32_process").Create($prog)'
```

and after the `if` statement call it like this:

```
invoke-expression $start
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Only thing I see now is the process runs as "NETWORK SERVICE". How can I have the process run as my user account so when I log in, I can see and use the program?

Comment: You have to change credential in task scheduler with yours user & pw

Comment: I've done that prior to this question (as you can see in my screenshots above it ran a lot of them as my username). When I implemented your fix and rebooted my machine it ran the script as NETWORK SERVICE. Any other thoughts? Can PowerShell invoke-expression as a user?

Comment: try $start = 'start-process $prog -credential $cred' .Where $cred are you credendials